# Windows phone 8 skype over 3G

Tags: skype

Skype on m'y phone runs on the background but it is only activated when I'm connected on my local WiFi network.

When using 3G (connected all the time) no Skype is ringing or do some notifications.

Can someone tell me if there is a setting to have Skype activated 24/7?

Comment: Does it sometimes work or do you get delayed notifications? It is meant to run in the background over 3G but "Some capabilities listed above are work-in-progress and may not function consistently". A lot of people are also saying that they don't get notifications or are delayed.

Comment: Hi, thenks fot the reply. Actually it rings only when I'm on Wi-Fi network. When I'm outside (at work f.ex.) and using 3G instead of Wi-fi. Even if people call me no ring at all on my Skype on WP8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I have updated the skype on my Windows Phone 8 and it started to work on 3G too.

Hope it was just deactivated by Microsoft feature...